# Select the second of two DIVs that have the same class name from an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an iframe with multiple `div` tags. I have no control over the div class names.

For that I have 2 DIVs with the same class name I want to select the second DIV with the content inside this DIV. I couldn't manage until now anything, I just can retrieve the whole iframe using the code below.

```
var myIFrame = document.getElementById("iframe");
var content = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
alert(content);   
$("#comment").val(content);
```

How do I retrieve the content of the second DIV?

Comment: Either check `.eq()` or `index`. Also, can you please post the HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you the content of the 2nd div with `.className`

```
$("div.className:eq(1)", content).html();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#iframe').contents().find('div.myClass').eq(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try navigating to the second div instead of stopping at the body.

```
var content = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.body.childNodes[1].innerHTML;
```

or

```
var content = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("div")[1].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the iframe is the same domain, the elements are easily accessible as

```
$("#iframe").contents().find(".somediv").eq(1);
```

reference: http://simple.procoding.net/2008/03/21/how-to-access-iframe-in-jquery/